# ValueError: time data '1520-18-12 00:00:00.000000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to convert `May 15 2018 12:00 AM` to `05 15 2018 12:00`. But during the conversion process, I am getting the following error message:

> ValueError: time data '1520-18-12 00:00:00.000000' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

```
${converted_date}=  Convert date  May 15 2018 12:00 AM  %m %d %Y %H:%M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to explicitly provide the format of the the source date, as the keyword did not succeed to automatically deduct it.
The problem is most probably with the beginning of the string, the "May" word in it. In time formatting directives this is `%b`; so this should do it:

```
${converted_date}=  Convert date  May 15 2018 12:00 AM  result_format=%m %d %Y %H:%M  date_format=%b %d %Y %H:%M
```

It's a bit hard to say from just this example is it `%b` - the 3 letterer abbreviated version of the month, or `%B` - the full name, as May is the only month that the 2 are the same :).

Here's a reference of python's time formatting directives - http://strftime.org.

Comment: On executing the above script, I'm getting this error: ValueError: unconverted data remains:  AM

Comment: ${converted_date}=  Convert date  May 15 2018 12:00 AM  result_format=%m %d %Y %H:%M  date_format=%b %d %Y %H:%M %p resolved the ValueError: unconverted data remains: AM